# Ruby on Rails install homebrew error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, homebrew, rbenv

I am using the command in terminal

```
> rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

It runs the command and this is the output:

```
> Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p247...
```

But the error message I get is

```
> BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.2 using ruby-build 20160130)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/tl/8vtvj5l967v6qjh162g3k2c40000gn/T/ruby-build.20160221132135.9296
Results logged to /var/folders/tl/8vtvj5l967v6qjh162g3k2c40000gn/T/ruby-build.20160221132135.9296.log

Last 10 log lines:
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/BryanSingh/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247
  --with-libyaml-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml
  --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
  --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline
  CC=clang
  CFLAGS= -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32 
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/BryanSingh/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib 
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/BryanSingh/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include
```

I tried using Google to find this error. But had no luck. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I've tried with 2.2.5 and 2.3.0, and that issues the same problem on OS X El Capitan. 
This track does not correct the problem : https://coderwall.com/p/wypzpq/install-ruby-failed-on-el-capitan

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by `homebrew` being unable to locate the extensions properly after an OS upgrade.

You'll need to update Xcode and then reinstall Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issue today.

I solved it by following instructions from RailsApp project 
Click [here](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) and go to the section "Install RVM"

After installing rvm

```
    $ rvm get stable --autolibs=enable
```

and follow the rest instructions as mentioned in the RailsApp project.